# elilo commandline boot config that includes spaces

Tags: linux, boot, efi, elilo

I've got an elilo (EFI LILO) config file that includes spaces in the label - like that:

```
image=/EFI/gentoo/boot/kernel-genkernel-ia64-3.1.6-gentoo
 label="Gentoo IA64 3.1.6"
 append="real_root=/dev/sda2"
 initrd=/EFI/gentoo/boot/initramfs-genkernel-ia64-3.1.6-gentoo
 read-only
```

How can I select this label from ELILO's command line - the usual suspects:

- `Gentoo IA64 3.1.6`
- `"Gentoo IA64 3.1.6"`
- `'Gentoo IA64 3.1.6'`
- `Gentoo\ IA64\ 3.1.6`

all fail with the 
`Kernel file not found Gentoo/"Gentoo/'Gentoo/Gentoo\`" kind of error.

Surely there must be a way to use a 'space' without making it a parameter delimeter?

Comment: How about `\x20` or `\040` or using another bootloader?

Comment: I'd take a look at \x20 or \040 next time I reboot this beast. I ended up editing the elilo.conf from EFI Shell edit command - do you know any better IA64 EFI bootloaders?